# sendKeys() passes only partial value or Not able to enter the date inputs into the date fields

Tags: protractor

I am using protractor version 5.2.2. I have 2 date fields in my project.I have used below codes for entering date inputs.

```
element(by.xpath("//*[@id='divContractInfo']/div[1]/div[2]/div/my-date-picker/div/div/input")).sendKeys("01-02-2019");
browser.sleep(5000);
element(by.xpath("//*[@id='divContractInfo']/div[1]/div[3]/div/my-date-picker/div/div/input")).sendKeys("12-02-2020");
```

Using this code,only the first character of the input is entered into the fist date field.But the second date input is fully entered into the second date field.

When i have used another code(given below ),the date values are fully entered into the date input box.But it gives validation error as 'date is required' while entering the rest of the fields in the form.What is the solution for this?

```
var inputEle = element(by.xpath("//*[@id='divContractInfo']/div[1]/div[2]/div/my-date-picker/div/div/input"));
var inputValue = 04-12-2020;
inputEle.click();
browser.executeScript('arguments[0].value=arguments[1]', 
                  inputEle.getWebElement(), 
                  inputValue);
```

The UI code(angular) is given below.

```
<div _ngcontent-c6="" class="frx-form-field-container">
  <label _ngcontent-c6="" class="frx-form-label">Effective Date:</label>
    <div _ngcontent-c6="" class="frx-form-input-field-container-small">
      <my-date-picker _ngcontent-c6="" class="frx-mydatepicker-field ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" formcontrolname="effectiveDate" frxconfirmequalvalidator="terminationDate" name="effectiveDate" ng-reflect-frx-confirm-equal-validator="terminationDate" ng-reflect-options="[object Object]" ng-reflect-name="effectiveDate" ng-reflect-frx-validate="[object Object]" ng-reflect-validation-message="" ng-reflect-status="false"><div class="mydp" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" style="width: 145px;"><!--bindings={
       "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"                 
       }--><div class="selectiongroup"><!--bindings={
      "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
      }--><input autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" class="selection ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" ngtype="text" spellcheck="false" ng-reflect-klass="selection" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" ng-reflect-is-disabled="false" ng-reflect-model="06-24-2018" aria-label="Date input field" placeholder="" style="height: 28px; font-size: 14px;"><div class="selbtngroup" style="height: 28px;"><!--bindings={
      "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
      }--> <!--bindings={
      "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
      }--> <!--bindings={
     "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
     }--><button class="btnclear btnclearenabled" type="button" ng-reflect-klass="btnclear" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]" aria-label="Clear Date"><span class="mydpicon icon-mydpremove"></span></button> <button class="btnpicker btnpickerenabled" type="button" ng-reflect-klass="btnpicker" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]" aria-label="Open Calendar"><span class="mydpicon icon-mydpcalendar"></span></button></div></div><!--bindings={
     "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
     }--></div></my-date-picker>
   </div>
</div>
<div _ngcontent-c6="" class="frx-form-field-container">
  <label _ngcontent-c6="" class="frx-form-label">Termination Date:</label>
    <div _ngcontent-c6="" class="frx-form-input-field-container-small">
      <my-date-picker _ngcontent-c6="" class="frx-mydatepicker-field ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" formcontrolname="terminationDate" frxconfirmequalvalidator="effectiveDate" name="terminationDate" ng-reflect-frx-confirm-equal-validator="effectiveDate" ng-reflect-options="[object Object]" ng-reflect-name="terminationDate" ng-reflect-frx-validate="[object Object]" ng-reflect-validation-message="" ng-reflect-status="false"><div class="mydp" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" style="width: 145px;"><!--bindings={
      "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
      }--><div class="selectiongroup"><!--bindings={
      "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
      }--><input autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" class="selection ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" ngtype="text" spellcheck="false" ng-reflect-klass="selection" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" ng-reflect-is-disabled="false" ng-reflect-model="06-24-2019" aria-label="Date input field" placeholder="" style="height: 28px; font-size: 14px;"><div class="selbtngroup" style="height: 28px;"><!--bindings={
     "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
     }--> <!--bindings={
    "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
     }--> <!--bindings={
    "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
    }--><button class="btnclear btnclearenabled" type="button" ng-reflect-klass="btnclear" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]" aria-label="Clear Date"><span class="mydpicon icon-mydpremove"></span></button> <button class="btnpicker btnpickerenabled" type="button" ng-reflect-klass="btnpicker" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]" aria-label="Open Calendar"><span class="mydpicon icon-mydpcalendar"></span></button></div></div><!--bindings={
   "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
   }--></div></my-date-picker>
 </div>
</div>
```

I am not understanding the reason behind the first date input is not entering fully.Thanks in advance.

Comment: does it work if you do: element(by.xpath("//*[@id='divContractInfo']/div[1]/div[2]/div/my-date-picker/div/div/input")).sendKeys("0");
and then element(by.xpath("//*[@id='divContractInfo']/div[1]/div[2]/div/my-date-picker/div/div/input")).sendKeys("1"); etcetera? If so, it may be a timing thing with how fast the keys are sent.

Comment: Thanks for your effort.I am able to enter the value successfully by passing it as sections/characters.In the first step,it detect only the first character ,so in the 2nd step, i have pass the rest of the characters fully into the field.Why it behave like this?

Comment: see https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/3196 but they claim it was fixed

Answer (score 0):

UI code for both the date picker seems to be same and so the element selection is proper. try adding `sleep` before entering the first date input.

Comment: I have tried with 8,10,15 milliseconds before entering the first date input but it doesn't help.

Comment: Try `click()` inside the date picker text box before sending value.
`element(by.xpath("//*[@id='divContractInfo']/div[1]/div[2]/div/my-date-picker/div/div/input")).click();browser.sleep(3000);
element(by.xpath("//*[@id='divContractInfo']/div[1]/div[2]/div/my-date-picker/div/div/input")).sendKeys("01-02-2019");`

Comment: I have tried the click() and wait before sending the value.But that also doesn't help.

Comment: Use `browser.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', '01-02-2019')", element(by.xpath("//*[@id='divContractInfo']/div[1]/div[2]/div/my-date-picker/div/div/input")));` instead of `element(by.xpath("//*[@id='divContractInfo']/div[1]/div[2]/div/my-date-picker/div/div/input")).sendKeys("01-02-2019");`

Comment: Thanks for your effort.But the above code also not work for me.I have updated the question.In that method i am able to enter the inputs fully into the fields.but it gives validation error.Any solution?Thanks in advance.